# MVVM: binding the View with the ViewModel with closures, unowned or weak self?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, closures, weak-references

I'm implementing a simple Master-Detail app where the *Master* `viewController` manages a table view which shows the results of a call to a REST service. The *Detail* `viewController` manages a view where I show more information about the item selected in the *Master*. Common scenario.

I'm trying to apply `MVVM` pattern. In the *Master* `viewController`, I create and initialize its `viewModel` this way:

```
lazy private var viewModel: ListViewModel = {
    return ListViewModel()
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    initViewModel()
}

private func initViewModel() {
    viewModel.onModelChange = { [weak self] () in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    viewModel.fetchData()
}
```

My question is: in the closure provided to the `viewModel`, should `self` be `weak` or `unowned` instead? I found an example implementing an scenario similar to mine that was setting it to `weak`, and another one setting it to `unowned`, so I'm not completely clear.

Comment: Your `viewModel` will never exist without the `self` (view controller). Thus, self will never be nil, you can safely use `unowned`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[unowned self]**. This tells your model not to hold a strong reference to `ViewController`

Apple document states it clearly that:

> “Like weak references, **an unowned reference** does not keep a strong
>   hold on the instance it refers to. Unlike a weak reference, however,
>   an unowned reference is assumed to always have a value”.

**In your case**, there is always be `ViewController`. So benefit of unowned reference is it’s `nonoptional`. No unwrap required each time it is used

Comment: Thanks. As said in a comment below my question also, I think that this would work for my particular scenario, since my "Master" view controller is the root one and its view model won't exist longer than itself.

Answer (score 3):

`Unowned` is used when you 100% sure the object won't be deallocated.

`weak` you then need to take care of its reference count issues.

```
viewModel.onModelChange = { [weak self] () in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    strongSelf.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I generally do it like this. You then hold a strong reference of `self` to avoid it being allocated during the block is running.

Comment: if you use [weak self], then self?.tableView.reloadData() is more enough

Comment: @MoayadAlkouz there will be a problem if you have multiple actions in the block. You never know when the self suddenly get niled.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `unowned` and `weak` is that `weak` is declared as an Optional while `unowned` isn't. If you know that self will not be `nil` use `unowned`, if you don't know: Use `weak`